# Нахождение меньшего числа из трех

Tags: python

Здравствуйте, есть файл с исходными данными:

```
-1 -2 -3
-4 -5 -6
-7 -8 -9
```

нужно сравнить числа построчно и найти меньшее:

```
f=open('input.txt','r')
for i in range(3):
    a,b,c=f.readline().split()
    print(a,' ',b,' ',c)
    if a<c:
        c=a
    if b<c:
        c=b
    print ('min =',c)
f.close()
```

Ответ:

```
-1   -2   -3
min = -1
-4   -5   -6
min = -4
-7   -8   -9
min = -7
```

Почему сравнивает абсолютные значения?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: вопрос на похожую тему: [How to sort three variables using at most two swaps?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3343530/4279)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`f.readline().split()` возвращает что? Правильно, список строк. **Строк**, вот оно и сравнивает их в лексикографическом порядке.

Исправляем строку для инициализации `a`, `b` и `c` на:

```
a,b,c=map(int, f.readline().split())
```

Comment: Объяснение неправильное, а исправление правильное. См. мой ответ

Comment: @Qwertiy Комментарий устарел, там была, скорее, опечатка, которая была исправлена после моего комментария. Предлагаю удалить все комментарии к этому ответу, чтобы не оставлять ненужное обсуждение.

Comment: чтобы сравнивать как числа, но при этом строки как есть возвращать (имеет значение для не-ascii цифр), [можно `key` параметр использовать:`result = min(f.readline().split(), key=int)`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455533/23044)

Answer (score 5):

Несколько замечаний по поводу кода:

1. Используя `for i in range(3)` Вы жестко задаете количетство строк в файле. Вместо этого можно просто пройти по файлу построчно.
2. Вместо того, чтобы вызывать `f.close()` можно воспользоваться блоком `with` - он автоматически закроет объект при выходе из блока.
3. В Python есть встроенная функция поиска минимума `min`.
4. Также в Python есть функция `str.join`, которая соединит строки, используя переданный ей разделитель.
5. Хорошей практикой является определение функции `main`, которая будет вызвана при исполнении скрипта. Это позволит избежать ненужного исполнения кода, если Вы заходите импортировать модуль в другой скрипт. Для этого используется условная конструкция `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Таким образом, Ваш код может быть улучшен следующим образом:

```
def main():
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            numbers = list(map(int, line.split()))
            print('   '.join(map(str, numbers)))
            print('min =', min(numbers))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: я первый раз вижу код на питоне и он мне. надо сказать, понравился. я только не понял, зачем list ? map наверняка должен возвращать массив. нет? Извините, если вопрос глупый :)

Comment: Это зависит от версии Python. В Python 2 `map` не является ленивой функцией и возвращает список. В Python 3 `map` возвращает итератор (является аналогом `itertools.imap` в Python 2). Соответственно, чтобы получить список из `map` я оборачиваю вызов функцией `list`.

Comment: Спасибо, почитал, кажется, даже что-то понял :)

Comment: Пишу кажется, потому что залез на eval и написал `for i in map(int, line.split())
  print i` думая, что я что-то понял. но не работает - правда, инвалид синтакс :) надо будет почитать про питон :)

Comment: Если `InvalidSyntax`, то, скорее всего, там стоит Python 3. В нем `print` является функцией, а не ключевым словом. Попробуйте добавить скобки вокруг `i`.

Comment: https://eval.in/376771

Comment: Двоеточие забыли после `for`.

Comment: https://eval.in/376774

Comment: Ладно, не буду вас мучать, почитаю для начала

Comment: https://eval.in/376775

Comment: А, Семен Семеныч !!!  спасибо :)

Comment: Спасибо за правку кода. С типами данных я сглупил, но, благодаря Вам, очередной раз поразился лаконичности кода python, которой мне еще учиться и учиться

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю к ответу @soon, что основная проблема вашего кода в том, что вы сравниваете строки, а не числа.

```
a, b, c = f.readline().split()
print(type(a))  # <class 'str'>
```

Таким образом, минимальное, что вам нужно сделать -- это преобразовать строки в числа, для этого используется функция `int`:

```
a, b, c = f.readline().split()
a, b, c = int(a), int(b), int(c)   # эту строку достаточно добавить
```

После такого исправления остальная программа работает правильно.

Правда, обычно используются более удобные способы преобразования:

```
a, b, c = map(int, f.readline().split())
```

или

```
a, b, c = (int(value) for value in f.readline().split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы найти в каждой входной строчке самое маленькое целое цисло:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import io

with io.open('input.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(min(line.split(), key=int))
```

Предполагается, что входной файл содержит на каждой строчке целые числа, разделённые пробелами. Это включает в себя числа состоящие из любых [десятичных цифр в Юникоде](https://codepoints.net/search?gc=Nd), закодированных используя utf-8 кодировку, например, если `input.txt` содержит тибетские цифры:

```
༩ ༥ ༧
༨ ༣ ༦
༤ ༠ ༡
```

то на выходе будет:

```
༥
༣
༠
```

Если при чтении использовать `min(map(int, line.split()))`, то результат:

```
5
3
0
```

В обоих случаях числа из файла сравниваются как числа.